# Jstl foreach Iterate list with class

Tags: foreach, jstl

I create list:

```
List<CheckoutDb> people = new ArrayList<CheckoutDb>();
```

I get info from database and add it to class:

```
CheckoutDb checkout = new CheckoutDb(rs.getInt("CheckOutNumber"),rs.getString("FirstName"));
```

i then add that to the list:

```
people.add(checkout);
```

**i can then do this to print out the list:**

```
for (CheckoutDb test : people) {
  System.out.println(test.getCheckOutNumber() + test.getFirstName() );
}
```

i send the list to a jsp file:

```
request.setAttribute("people", people);
```

**My question is: How can i do that same iteration in jstl?**

I have done this but does not print out the same:

```
    <c:forEach items="${people}" var="item">
        <td> ${item}</td>
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach items="${people}" var="item">
        <td> ${item.getFirstName()}</td>
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach items="${people}" var="item">
        <td> ${people}</td>
    </c:forEach>
```

Outputs:
goldenoaks.data.CheckoutDb@6f0602e0, goldenoaks.data.CheckoutDb@712ea5db, goldenoaks.data.CheckoutDb@3e3dc69e, goldenoaks.data.CheckoutDb@31e05b52,

if i do:

```
${people.size()}
```

it outputs correct size

and if i do this, it only prints last item in list:

```
        <c:forEach var="people" items="${checkedOutList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${people.firstName} ${people.lastName}</td>

        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code doesn't print a CheckoutDb as you're doing in your JSP code.. It also doesn't print the whole list as you're doing in the JSP code.

It prints the `checkOutNumber` property and the `firstName` property of each item in the list. So the equivalent would be (assuming that you want a table row per item)

```
<c:forEach items="${people}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${item.checkOutNumber}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${item.firstName}" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i did this before but nothing prints out, its completely blank.

Comment: Then your people list is probably empty.

Comment: but when i do ${books.size()} its got the exact amount i put in.

Comment: and when i do this: <c:forEach var="people" items="${people}">
            <tr>
                <td>${people.checkOutNumber} ${people.lastName}</td>
       
        </c:forEach>

Comment: Then you're not getting someting completely blank. Look at the generated HTML code (right-click - view page source), and you should see the <tr>s and <td>s.

Comment: it only prints last item.

Comment: Also, decide if your attribute is named people or books.